# X server not starting

Tags: kubuntu, xorg, kde5, sddm

Today, when I turned on my PC and logged in, plasma was not starting, so I decided to hit `Ctrl+Alt+F2` to change to a terminal.

Then I executed `startx` but it wasn't providing output. Then I tried to cancel the command, pressing `Ctrl+C`, but then it started the X Server and it started working.

I tried the same way 3 times and it worked.

I'm wondering why the command `startx` works only after pressing `Ctrl+C`. Maybe that prevents sddm to start plasma?

Comment: I'm not sure you're on the right track here.  If I were you I would be trying to solve the problem that X is not starting when you log on. What version and flavour of Ubuntu are you using? When did the problem start? What kinds of things had you done on the device leading up to the problem's onset?

Comment: @Nmath I'm using Kubuntu 20.04, the problem started this morning. I think i did nothing to get this but yesterday i started X server in recovery mode. Sorry, I'm new to Linux